# drop down menu is blocking my nav login form

Tags: html, css

I have the following drop down menu and when expanded, it seems to be blocking my login form as shown in the picture below. I am not sure if I should use codepen to but anyway, here is my css code:

```
.nav {
  width: 200%;



}

#nav-icon {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  color:  #ffffff;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

div.nav ul, div.nav li, label{
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2em;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;


}

div.nav ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

header div.nav-login{
   float:left;
   position: absolute;
   left: 90em;
   top: 5.5em;

}


header div.nav-login ::placeholder {
   color: #6A5ACD;
   opacity: 1;

}

header div.nav-login input[type='password'] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 130px;
}

header div.nav-login input[type='password']::placeholder {
  position: relative;
  left: 1em;
}

 header div.nav-login form{
    padding-top: 40px;

}

header div.nav-login form input{
   float:left;
   width: 8em;
   height: 3em;
   padding-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border:none;
   background-color: #ccc;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #111;
   line-height: 20px;
   position: absolute;
}

header div.nav-login form button{
   float:left;
   width: 60px;
   height: 30px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border:none;
   background-color: #FFF8DC;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #111;
   cursor:pointer;
   position: absolute;
   left: 19em;
   top: 3.2em;

}

header div.nav-login form button:hover{
   background-color: #ccc;

}
```

Those are most of my code for that section and I definately need that z index to be there so that it won't be behind my table but now I can't use the login form when the drop down menus are expanded....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgk8G.png)

Comment: could you please share on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: It doesn't look quite right on codepen. I would like to give you my live website but they are in the process of renewing their license but I realise that if I moved my login form to the top, then it does work but not underneath my welcome title

Comment: The other thing that I can do is to change the width and height of my login page but then my placeholder will become too small to read

Comment: with .8em in font size

Comment: I think the main problem is my z-index but I also have a table that is behind my drop down menu and when I put z-index 10 for login form, 9 for drop down menu and 8 for table, the drop down menu is still behind the table

Comment: I found a solution but not sure if it is the best... I gave a max-height to my drop down menu and set overflow to scroll... At least, it won't block my table